# Many to one joins

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Lets say I have the following tables:

```
create table table_a
(
  id_a,
  name_a,
  primary_key (id_a)
);

create table table_b
(
  id_b,
  id_a is not null, -- (Edit)
  name_b,
  primary_key (id_b),
  foreign_key (id_a) references table_a (id_a)
);
```

We can create a join view on these tables in a number of ways:

```
create view join_1 as
(
  select 
    b.id_b, 
    b.id_a, 
    b.name_b, 
    a.name_a 
  from table_a a, table_b b
  where a.id_a = b.id_a
);

create view join_2 as
(
  select 
    b.id_b, 
    b.id_a, 
    b.name_b, 
    a.name_a 
  from table_b b left outer join table_a a
  on a.id_a = b.id_a
);

create view join_3 as
(
  select 
    b.id_b, 
    b.id_a, 
    b.name_b, 
    (select a.name_a from table_a a where b.id_b = a.id_a) as name_a 
  from table_b b;
);
```

Here we know:

(1) There must be at least one entry from `table_a` with `id_a` (due to the foreign key in table B) AND
(2) At most one entry from `table_a` with `id_a` (due to the primary key on table A)

then we know that there is exactly one entry in `table_a` that links in with the join.

Now consider the following SQL:

```
select id_b, name_b from join_X;
```

Note that this selects no columns from `table_a`, and because we know in this join, `table_b` joins to exactly one we really shouldn't have to look at `table_a` when performing the above select.

So what is the best way to write the above join view?

Should I just use the standard `join_1`, and hope the optimizer figures out that there is no need to access `table_a` based on the primary and foreign keys?

Or is it better to write it like `join_2` or even `join_3`, which makes it more explicit that there is exactly one row from the join for each row from `table_b`?

**Edit + additional question**

Is there any time I should prefer a sub-select (as in `join_3`) over a normal join (as in `join_1`)?

Comment: The edit adding `IS NOT NULL` is redundant due to the FK constraint, which can't logically bind to a NULL record in table_a.

Comment: @Dems, fortunately, a FK constraint is **not** implicitly a `NOT NULL` constraint, in most RDBMS! That would be a severe functionality loss! How would you model a zero-or-one relationship? See this question, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice

Comment: @Dems... hmm, after googling it really seems that SQL Server has a limitation there. Incredible!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Intuitively, I'd think `join_1` will perform slightly slower, because your assumption that the optimiser can transform the join away is wrong as you didn't declare the `table_b.id_a` column to be `NOT NULL`. In fact, this means that (1) is wrong. `table_b.id_a` can be `NULL`. Even if you know it can't be, the optimiser doesn't know that.</strike>

As far as `join_2` and `join_3` is concerned, depending on your database, optimisation might be possible. The best way to find out is to run (Oracle syntax)

```
EXPLAIN select id_b, name_b from join_X;
```

And study the execution plan. It will tell you whether `table_a` was joined or not. On the other hand, if your view should be reusable, then I'd go for the plain `join` and forget about pre-mature optimisations. You can achieve better results with proper statistics and indexes, as a `join` operation is not always so expensive. But that depends on your statistics, of course.

Comment: The omission of "not null" for table_b.id_a was not intentional, I've now edited the question and added that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

1 + 2 are effectively identical under SQL Server.

I have never used [3], but it looks quite odd. I would strongly suspect the optimizer will make it equivalent to the other 2.

It's a good exercise to run all 3 statements and compare the execution plans produced.

So given identical performance, the clearest to read gets my vote - [2] is the standard where it is supported otherwise [1].

In your case, if you don't want any columns from A, why include Table_A in the statement anyway?

If it's simply a filter - i.e. only include rows from Table B where a row exists in Table A even though I don't want any cols from Table A, then all 3 syntaxes are fine, although you may find that use of IF EXISTS is more performant in some dbs:

```
 SELECT * from Table_B b WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_A a WHERE b.id_b = a.id_a)
```

although in my experience this is usual equivalent in performance to any of the others.

You also ask, then would you choose a subquery over the other expressions. This boils down to whether it's a CORRELATED subquery or not.

Basically - a correlated subquery has to be run once for every row in the outer statement - this is true of the above - for every row in Table B you must run the subquery against Table A.

If the subquery can be run just once

```
 SELECT * from Table_B b WHERE b.id_a IN (SELECT a.id_a FROM Table_A a WHERE a.id_a > 10)
```

Then the subquery is generally more performant than a join - although I suspect that some optimizers will still be able to spot this and reduce both to the same execution plan.

Again, the best thing to do is to run both statements, and compare execution plans.

Finally and most simply - given the FK you could just write:

```
 SELECT * From Table_B b WHERE b.id_a IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is that true, about 1+2 being identical? In Oracle, `outer joins` are quite different from `inner joins`, *especially* for the optimiser

Comment: Functionally they're the same, due to the constraints put in place by the foreign key.  JOINing table_b with table_a can yield a subset of table_a, but always the complete set of table_b.  Thus, `SELECT b.* FROM b INNER JOIN a` yields the same result as using a LEFT JOIN.  Combine this with SQL Server's oprimiser (which does analyse the constraints) you end up with just a scan of table_b, and no use of table_a in the execution plan.

Comment: `table_b.id_a` is nullable. So inner joining will apply `table_b.id_a IS NOT NULL`, whereas outer joining will not...

Comment: You can't put a NULL into `table_a.id_a` due to the PRIMARY KEY (in SQL Server at least), and `table_b.id_a` *must* reference an instance of `table_a.id_a`.  Thus your scenario can't occur.

Comment: @Dems: Not `table_A.id_a`. I thought `table_B.id_a` was nullable. But the OP corrected the question so this thought is obsolete...

Comment: @Dems - Not true in the SQL systems I work on. NULL in a FK referencing column means that the FK constraint isn't checked. (Also true for composite keys - if `(a,b)` references `(c,d)`, and `b` is null in a particular row, `a` can have any value, regardless of whether that values appears in `c` or not)

Comment: I defer to your knowledge for other RDBMS, but, as quoted from my comment, `In SQL Server at least` the statement is true in my experience.

Comment: @Dems - I was specifically addresses the possibility of `table_B.id_a` being null (absent the not null constraint). It's definitely possible in SQL Server for the *referencing* column of a FK constraint to be null.

Comment: @Dems - There is no requirement for a FK field to be non-nullable in any RDBMS system I have ever used, which includes SQL Server. Generally, they are, and many people make the same supposition - but there is nothing wrong with table_B.id_a being null.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using views at all for this purpose? If you want to get data from the table, get it from the *table.*

Or, if you need a view to translate some columns in the tables (such as coalescing NULLs into zeros), create a view over just the `B` table. This will also apply if some DBA wanna-be has implemented a policy that all selects must be via views rather than tables :-)

In both those cases, you don't have to worry about multi-table access.

Comment: I guess this is some simplified example for a much more complex use case. I wouldn't judge too early about wanna-be's, we have a similar setup in our app for good reasons

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the platform.

SQL Server both analyses the logical implications of constraints (foreign keys, primary keys, etc) and expands VIEWs inline.  This means that the 'irrelevant' portion of the VIEW's code is obsoleted by the optimiser.  SQL Server would give the exact same execution plan for all three cases.  (Note; there is a limit to the complexity that the optimiser can handle, but it can certainly handle this.)

Not all platforms are created equal, however.
- Some may not analyse constraints in the same way, assuming you coded the join for a reason
- Some may pre-compile the VIEW's execution/explain plan

As such, to determine behaviour, you must be aware of the specific platform's capabilties.  In the vast majority of situations the optimiser is a complex beast, and so the best test is simply to try it and see.

**EDIT**

In response to your extra question, are correlated sub-queries every prefered? There is no simple answer, as it depends on the data and the logic you are trying to implement.

There are certainly cases int he past where I have used them, both to simplify a query's structure (for maintainability), but also to enable specific logic.

If the field `table_b.id_a` referenced many entries in table_a you may only want the name from the latest one.  And you *could* implement that using `(SELECT TOP 1 name_a FROM table_a WHERE id_a = table_b.id_a ORDER BY id_a DESC)`.

In short, it depends.
- On the query's logic
- On the data's structure
- On the code's final layout

More often than not I find it's not needed, but measurably often I find that it is a positive choice.

Note:

Depending on the correlated sub-query, it doesn't actually always get executed 'once for every record'.  SQL Server, for example, expands the required logic to be executed in-line with the rest of the query.  It's important to note that SQL code is processed/compiled/whatever before being executed.  SQL is simply a method for articulating set based logic, which is then transformed into traditional loops, etc, using the most optimal algorithms available to the optimiser.

Other RDBMS may perform differently, due to the capabilities or limitations of the optimiser.  Some RDBMS perform well when using `IN (SELECT blah FROM blah)`, or when using `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM blah)`, butsome perform terribly.  The same applies to correlated sub-queries.  Sub perform exceptionally well with them, some don't perform so well, but most handle the very well in my experience.