# Foreign key that can also be zero

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

When I am using Foreign Keys in MySQL, I will get an error if the source value is 0 (because there is no target record with ID 0). Therefore, I am changing the source column to be NULL, and then it works. However, I am not sure if this is the right way this should be done. Is it the right way, or can I somehow keep the source ID set to 0 instead of NULL?

Comment: What difference does it make to you if it's `0` or `NULL`? Not to mention that from a logical standpoint, `0` simply does not make sense.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Foreign keys are constraints. This means that if the value of the column that has the foreign key is set to anything (and "anything" does not include `NULL`), that value must exist in the referenced table or MySQL will throw an error.

So, in short, you can either set the value to `NULL`, remove the foreign key constraint and set the value to whatever you desire, including `0`, or add a record with a `0` in the referenced table. Of these options setting the value to `NULL` seems the cleanest.

Answer (score 6):

It is the right way. 0 is a value and null says that there is nothing in the column.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is the right way. The whole point of an FK is to enforce that a record with the referenced ID actually exists. So if you set the FK column to 0, there must be a record with ID 0.

The only way around this is to make the FK column NULLable, as you did.

At any rate, why would you want to set the FK column to 0? The canonical value for "does not exist" in SQL is NULL.

Comment: I can think of one reason: it's easier to write queries. For example, you can write a check like this: `...WHERE order_id = :orderId` and pass `orderId` as `123` (valid) or `0` (missing/unimportant). So you won't have to write workaround like `WHERE COALESCE(order_id, 0) = :orderId`

Answer (score 4):

using a NULL is better than zero for two reasons.  first, it's clearer that it's a "special" value (there's nothing that forces table ids to always be non-zero, although it is often true for auto-generated ids), and second it works in SQL with the foreign key constraint.

so what you are doing is common practice - many people use NULL as a marker that says "missing value", and that's what SQL's foreign key constraint expects.

another way to handle missing values is to use a third "link" table that has an entry only if there is a connection between the two classes (as you would do in a many-to-many relation).  this avoids the need for a NULL, and so is preferred by some database purists, but makes everything more complex.  see [Nullable Foreign Key bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice) for more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the right way and the correct pattern to use in those cases.

As stated, what is indicated in those structures is to leave the column as null, indicating the line would not be linked to any counterpart in the foreign table. It whould not be considered "right" in database teories, but is a very used pattern, so, its not actualy considered "wrong" by the most of database designers. I gues you could say its the kind of pattern you try not to look to when trying to find mistakes in the structure.

The pattern is considered incorrect because it is expected to use a non-null column in a primary key and in this sense the columns in the table that will receive the key must be identical to the primary column of the table, that is, they would never be null. However, in most databases physically, there are no impediments to creating a different column, which makes the null value possible.

The problem with this architecture is when the table gets too big, when, p. eg, it have more than 1000 lines (yes, the "big" would be that low!), in these situations, specially in a small infrastructure, the answer time starts to get too long and "questionable". It happens that null records can not be part of indexes and the algorithm ends up doing a full scan. Therefor this type of pattern is implemented when we know the table will always be verry, verry small! Otherwise, I recommend use the pattern creating an external table where the "null" option in your case would be a "not found" in this other table.