# one to optional many Relationship

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, constraints, entity-relationship

I want to create one to optional many relation between following two table.

```
'FK_transactionmember' FOREGIN KEY ('MemberID') REFERENCES 'member' ('ID')
```

I create foreign key constrain witch is **one-to-many** relation(Above). In this case member ID must required for transaction, but member is optional.

**How to control this optional situation?**

**Memebr:**

```
CREATE TABLE `member` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FirstName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`LastName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`PermanentAddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`TemporaryAddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`Zip` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`City` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`LastVisit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`TotalVisit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`Active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Transaction**

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`MemberID` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`UserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Total` float DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at last) two ways create table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`MemberID` int(11) NULL,
`UserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Total` float DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
CONSTRAINT 'FK_transactionmember' 
    FOREGIN KEY ('MemberID') 
    REFERENCES 'member' ('ID')
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

and set `MemberID` to `null` whenever you can't connect it with member. It's fine in my opinion but it doesn't meet [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) requirements or use different table to link both tables like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `MemberTransactions` (
`MemberID` int(11) NULL,
`TransactionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

CONSTRAINT 'FK_member' 
    FOREGIN KEY ('MemberID') 
    REFERENCES 'member' ('ID')
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT 'FK_transaction' 
    FOREGIN KEY ('TransactionID') 
    REFERENCES 'transaction' ('ID')
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

and then `transaction` table without `MemberID` column.

**Added** similar question: [Nullable Foreign Key bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

If the MemberID is optional then its default value must be null, not zero. Therefore if no data exists the null value will be allowed.

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `MemberID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `UserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Total` float DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `FK_transactionmember` (`MemberID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_transactionmember` FOREGIN KEY (`MemberID`) REFERENCES `member` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```