# One to Many optional relationship Mysql- Null or table between

Tags: mysql

Ok I have an album and image table.

An album can have many images.

However an image may not always belong to an album. It could be stand alone.

Is it better practice to add  null on the album_id in the image table or create an table in between with album_id and image_id. As an image can only belong to one album I would add a unique contraint to the image_id in the join table.

So option 1) null field in image table
option 2) join table with unique constraint on image_id

I have read that this is either identifying or non identifying relationship. If I have an non identifying relationship the field would still need to be set as null correct. An non identifying relationship in other words needs to be set to non- mandatory - with a null correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally - i would put the table in between.

this will allow you to have images by themselves.
and albums by themselves.
and when appropriate, you can associate them in the middle table.  the same image on multiple albums, multiple images on the same album.

if you go this way, you will never need to change yout table definitions later - even when your business rules change.

Comment: adding null on the album_id on image table allows them to stand alone though still right? and would be quicker on the query select right, not sure if this is best practice though

Comment: yes - an image with a null album_id would be 'stand-alone' - but to me, if you are talking about images that do not belong on an album, then images should be completely separate from albums for normalization.

Answer (score 2):

If the relationship is one-to-many, a `NULL` on the `images.album_id` is more appropriate here.  When defining the `album_id` and its foreign key constraint on your `images` table, permitting `NULL` is a signal that an image may have no parent album.  This design permits a one-to-many albums to images, while allowing orphan images as well.

```
CREATE TABLE albums (
  album_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  othercol VARCHAR()
)
CREATE TABLE images (
  image_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  album_id INT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES albums (album_id)
)
```

If an image needs to belong to multiple albums in a many-to-many relationship, you will need a table in between to relate them. This still permits orphan when there's no related rows in `album_images` for a given image.

```
CREATE TABLE albums (
  album_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  othercol VARCHAR()
)
CREATE TABLE images (
  image_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  othercol VARCHAR()
)
/* Link albums to images as many times as necessary */
CREATE TABLE album_images (
  album_id INT NOT NULL,
  image_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES albums (album_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES images (image_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  /* composite key on the two, ensuring uniqueness */
  PRIMARY KEY (album_id, image_id)
)
```

Comment: I thought this broke normalisation though?

Comment: No it doesn't break normalization unless an image can belong to more than one album, which I didn't get from your question.  If an image could have multiple parents (many to many), you would need a table in between.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice says a table in between is best practice. Surely this is slower however.

Comment: @MatthewChambers While the accepted answer there advocates an intermediary table, note that the answer with far more votes advocates a nullable FK.