# What Normal Form would nullable Foreign Keys violate?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

A co-worker explained to me that Nullable Foreign Keys are considered bad practice in database design because it violates one of the early normal forms. While I took a basic database class in school, I don't think that normal forms were discussed as a topic. Wikipedia and other websites that discuss this topic use academic terms, but I'd like to understand this aspect of normal forms better without having to take a whole class on them.

I recognize that [not everybody feels nullable foreign keys are bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice): this question is not opening up a debate on that matter. Instead, I would like a concrete understanding of how they relate to the topic of Normal Forms. Which Normal Forms are violated by nullable foreign keys, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Erwin Smout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724420/562459) answers that question in the Q/A you linked.

Date wrote this in the 7th ed. of *An Introduction to Database Systems*.

> First normal form: A relvar is in 1NF if and only if, in every legal
>   value of that relvar, every tuple contains exactly one value for each
>   attribute. (p 357)

And also

> The whole point about nulls is precisely that they are not
>   values--they are, to repeat, marks or flags. (p 584)

So in Date's opinion, a relvar that allows nulls in any column isn't in 1NF.

His chapter "Missing information" has a lot about this topic.