# Under what conditions must a foreign key not be null?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nullable Foreign Key bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice)

I know foreign keys are used to relate or link different tables but my assignment is asking for specific conditions for the subject matter.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please write your question completely in the body — the title should be a synopsis of the question, but the question itself should be written out in full in the body of the question.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key may not be null when it is part of a composite primary key in the child table.

```
tableA
id (int) PK

tableB
id (int) PK

tableAB
aId (int)
bId (int)
(aId, bId) PK
```

Answer (score 1):

A FOREIGN KEY constraint can contain null values; however, if any column of a composite FOREIGN KEY constraint contains null values, verification of all values that make up the FOREIGN KEY constraint is skipped. To make sure that all values of a composite FOREIGN KEY constraint are verified, specify NOT NULL on all the participating columns.

Answer (score 0):

Some ORMs need FKs to be nullable because of the way they link entities and manage dependencies.