# How do I correctly compare Options members in Slick?

Tags: scala, database-design, database-schema, option-type, slick-2.0

I'm doing things with Addresses, and the member **subpremise**(apartment/condo #) causes retrieves to miss.  I also have concerns about subpremise being a part of my unique index constraint, given it can be null.

Failure filter:

```
tableQuery.filter(c=> (c.longitude === r.longitude && c.latitude === r.latitude) ||
        (c.streetNumber === r.streetNumber && c.route === r.route && c.subpremise === r.subpremise && c.neighborhoodId === r.neighborhoodId))
```

Successful filter: (by removung subpremise)

```
tableQuery.filter(c=> (c.longitude === r.longitude && c.latitude === r.latitude) ||
            (c.streetNumber === r.streetNumber && c.route === r.route && c.neighborhoodId === r.neighborhoodId))
```

I've included the definitions below s.t. if there is another contributing factor that I've missed, hopefully it will be noticed.

```
case class Address(id:Option[Long],streetNumber:Short,route:String,subpremise:Option[String],neighborhoodId:Fk,latitude:Option[Double],longitude:Option[Double])

class Addresses(tag: Tag) extends Table[Address](tag, "addresses") with Logging {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def streetNumber = column[Short]("street_number")
  def route = column[String]("route",O.NotNull)
  def subpremise = column[Option[String]]("subpremise")
  def neighborhoodId = column[Long]("neighborhood",O.NotNull)
  def latitude = column[Option[Double]]("latitude")
  def longitude = column[Option[Double]]("longitude")

  //Constraints
  def idx = index("idx_streetnum_route_subpremise_neighborhood", (streetNumber,route,subpremise,neighborhoodId), unique = true)
  def gps = index("gps", (latitude,longitude), unique = true)

  //Foreign Key
  def neighborhood = foreignKey("NEIGHBORHOOD_FK", neighborhoodId, Neighborhoods.tableQuery)(_.id)

  def * = (id.?,streetNumber,route,subpremise,neighborhoodId,latitude,longitude) <> (Address.tupled,Address.unapply)
}
```

Comment: For future readers, I suggest you eliminate a bunch of this code (i.e., everything that's not directly relevant to the problem---all those extra fields).

Answer (score 4):

The answer was to use the following check.

```
( //Option Scenario both are defined
  (c.subpremise.isDefined && r.subpremise.isDefined && c.subpremise === r.subpremise) ||
  //Option Scenario both are empty
  (c.subpremise.isEmpty && r.subpremise.isEmpty)
)
```

Comment: You can probably avoid checking `isDefined`: `c.optField === r.optField || (c.optField.isEmpty && r.optField.isEmpty)`

Comment: AaronNovstrup you are 100% right, I just verified/tested it. Thanks!!

Comment: An answer that explains *why* you need those seemingly redundant checks would be helpful. Hopefully a Slick/SQL guru will come along and provide such an answer, but I suspect that it has to do SQL's three-valued logic. An equality comparison in three-valued logic does not return `true` if either value is NULL.

Comment: That is it. To quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724420/3404097): "WHERE x=y" in SQL actually means "WHERE x is not null and y is not null and x=y".

Answer (score 1):

My solution that working with Slick 3.3.x

```
tableQuery
  .filterIf(r.subpremise.isEmpty)(_.subpremise.isEmpty) // 1. both are empty
  .filterOpt(r.subpremise)(_.subpremise === _) // 2. both are defined and equal
```

Case 1 (r.subpremise is empty) corresponds the following SQL:

```
select * from addresses where subpremise is null
```

Case 2 (r.subpremise isn't empty):

```
select * from addresses where subpremise = ?
```