# EF code first from database 0..1 to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to generated an entity framework code first model from an existing database (without changing the database schema).  This database has been used in the past to generate edmx models and I am trying to achieve the equivalent model using Fluent Api or data annotations.

The relationship I have been unable to reproduce is 0..1 to many using a join table (not a nullable foreign key).

So it would look something like this:

```
TableA
{
   ID (PrimaryKey)
   TableB (0 or 1)
}

JoinTable
{
   TableA_FK (PrimaryKey, ForeignKey),
   TableB_FK (ForeignKey)
}

TableB
{
   ID (PrimaryKey)
   TableAs (Many)
}
```

Is this achievable in the code first style or will I have to generate an edmx model in order to use this database in EF without changing its schema?

Many thanks,
Phil

Comment: You could allllmost do it with [Entity Splitting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.7) but I think that requires a row in the join table for every row in TableA

Comment: What does the database model look like? If `JoinTable` has a PK/FK referring to tableA, the association can only be * (A) to 0..1 (B).

Comment: Have I got it mixed up?  Basically A may might have a B (though many don't)  B might have many As, although most have none.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example without using a JoinTable class. The join table is configured through the fluent api.

```
class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        { }

        public DbSet<TableA> TableA { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TableB> TableB { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>().ToTable("TableA");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>().ToTable("TableB");

            modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>()
                .HasMany(x => x.TableAs)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("JoinTable");
                    m.MapLeftKey("TableA_FK");
                    m.MapRightKey("TableB_FK");
                });
        }
    }

    class TableA
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public TableB TableB { get; set; }
    }

    class TableB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TableA> TableAs { get; set; }
    }
```

This will generate the following migration script, which looks like the schema you have.

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.TableA",
        c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                TableB_ID = c.Int(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.TableB", t => t.TableB_ID)
        .Index(t => t.TableB_ID);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.TableB",
        c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.JoinTable",
        c => new
            {
                TableA_FK = c.Int(nullable: false),
                TableB_FK = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.TableA_FK, t.TableB_FK })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.TableB", t => t.TableA_FK, cascadeDelete: true)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.TableA", t => t.TableB_FK, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.TableA_FK)
        .Index(t => t.TableB_FK);

}
```

Comment: You're ending up with two separate relationships: a 1:1 between TableA and TableB, and a many:many between the same tables using a join table

Comment: Yes, but can that be avoided if it needs to match the schema? In my understanding this matches the schema described in the question.

Comment: This is the closest answer I've seen to what I'd like to achieve.  One issue that strikes me from looking at the code is that the primary key is not quite right on the join table in the migration but that may not be an issue as the db already exists.

Comment: Also having trouble loading data using this approach.  I might have made a mistake in the setup but I'm getting The specified table '[JoinTable]' was not found in the model. Ensure that the table name has been correctly specified.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, the following code using only data annotations should create your model.

```
public class TableA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public JoinTable JoinTable { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<JoinTable> JoinTables{ get; set; }
}

public class JoinTable
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("TableA")]
    public int TableA_FK { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TableB")]
    public int TableB_FK { get; set; }

    public TableA TableA { get; set; }

    public TableB TableB { get; set; }
}
```

Interestingly, EF does not perform a round trip back to the original, if you generate the code-first models from the database model that this code creates then EF simplifies the model and removes the join table and creates a nullable foreign key.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This seems close to what I would like.  It would be a complete answer if TableA could refer to its TableB directly without going through the join table.  This happens in the database-first edmx model approach - the join table gets hidden in the model.

Comment: @PhilWithington Yeah, I know what you mean. I'm not sure how to achieve this. You could possibly have another `NotMapped` property that dereferences the `JoinTable` property.

Comment: Good suggestion.  The lack of round-trip may be problematic in the future though.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe you're missing some concepts here...

Why you have a JoinTable if it's doesn't have any column besides its foreign keys? It doesn't make sense... IHMO a nullable foreign key in TableA would be correct way.

When you work with Code-First it means that everything in your database will be represented by CODE. There's no reason to have a table in your database but not in your code...

EDMX handles that relationship because it uses "Associations" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713299#Overview

...backing to the code-first, you can represent your database like this:

```
 public class JoinTable
 {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int TableA_FK { get; set; }

        public int TableB_FK { get; set; }

        //a future property here

        public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }

        public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }
 }

 public partial class TableA
 {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TableAId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual JoinTable JoinTable { get; set; }
}


public partial class TableB
{
        public TableB()
        {
            JoinTable = new HashSet<JoinTable>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TableBId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<JoinTable> JoinTable { get; set; }
    }
}

public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<JoinTable> JoinTable { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TableA> TableA { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TableB> TableB { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.JoinTable)
            .WithRequired(e => e.TableA);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>()
            .HasMany(e => e.JoinTable)
            .WithRequired(e => e.TableB)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.TableB_FK)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that nullable foreign keys are more practical, especially when working when with EF code first.  However it can be argued either way in terms of relational database say e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice.  In my case though I need to reverse engineer code first from an existing db.  Your solution does not represent the model as edmx approach would.

Comment: I never said that my solution represents the model as edmx does. What I said was, IN MY OPINION, the edmx approach does not make sense when using code-first, because there's no reason to have a table in your database but not in your code

Comment: A many to many relationship would create a table in the database but not in the model would it not?

Comment: @PhilWithington: Only for that specific case (and for entity splitting)

Comment: @PhilWithington yeah, it would, but I was talking about the situation of your question, sorry