# Creating foreign key constraints for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a table called `ProjectList`. I have two other tables called `Estimates` and `Orders`.

The Primary keys for `Estimates` and `Orders` <del>and</del> *are* foreign keys in `ProjectList`. A `ProjectList` record is created first, then `Estimate` records are created and then and an `Order` record.

How would I create foreign key constraints in `ProjectList` for `Estimates` and `Orders` without violating the <del>Order</del> foreign key constraints?

The only thing I can think of is create an empty Orders record when an Estimate is created.  Not sure if that is an elegant solution.

Comment: What is an "empty record"? The convention is, to create a PL 1st use null FKs. (But designs with null always have null-free equivalents.) This is a faq. (Obviously.) Please don't ask duplicate questions.  Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable Foreign Key bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723808/nullable-foreign-key-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the root problem here is a *logical error*: your DB model claims that it is possible to have a project estimate and an order before the project exists.
To illustrate the point, a logical model should look somehow like this:

```
-- Project PRO exists.
--
project {PRO}
     PK {PRO}
```

```
-- Project estimate number EST_NO of project PRO exists.
--
estimate {PRO, EST_NO}
      PK {PRO, EST_NO}

      FK {PRO} REFERENCES project {PRO}
```

```
-- Project order number ORD_NO of project PRO exists.
--
order {PRO, ORD_NO}
   PK {PRO, ORD_NO}

   FK {PRO} REFERENCES project {PRO}
```

Note how you can not create an estimate or an order before the project. If for some reason you *prefer single column IDs*, then the example can be modified as:

```
-- Project PRO_ID exists.
--
project {PRO_ID}
     PK {PRO_ID}

-- Project estimate identified by EST_ID
-- for project PRO_ID exists.
--
estimate {EST_ID, PRO_ID}
      PK {EST_ID}

      FK {PRO_ID} REFERENCES project {PRO_ID}

-- Project order identified by ORD_ID
-- for project PRO_ID exists.
--
order {ORD_ID, PRO_ID}
   PK {ORD_ID

   FK {PRO_ID} REFERENCES project {PRO_ID}
```

So, `FKs` in your example are reversed. Database design is all about logic, it stems from it. Although you may find a way to band-aid around the *perceived technical problem* using some SQL trickery, the underlying logical error (bug) will remain.

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: The exact meanings of the entities, relationships & rules aren't made clear in the question. So there's no evidence that some question entities can't exist before others & there's no evidence of existence "errors" for FKs because SQL FKs can be null. Re reversed FKs, "then Estimate records are created" does sound suspicious but we need clarification from the asker.